# Warning because of 1 down-vote?

Tags: support

These are my questions & answer at Server Fault:

[image]

which is a score of 0.4 - at least positive. I receive the warning when i want to ask a question:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a
>   good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Do 3 up-votes, 1 no-score and 1 down-vote [with **no down-vote** for my answers] already trigger this warning?

---

I don't have any deleted question and the revision history shows only one negative entry:

[image]

Honestly, I consider it from my point of view a bit *cruel*.

**Can somebody explain me why 1 down-vote of -2 already triggers the warning?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the annoying things is that de user interface hides deleted Q&A's even from the user who posted them.

Once you achieve [>10k rep](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) a search of [`deleted:1`](https://serverfault.com/search?q=user%3A277875+deleted%3A1) combined with your user ID will list the deleted questions and answers for your user.
It looks like you don't have enough reputation yet to be able to list your own deleted posts that way.

I *think* deleted posts still count towards generating that warning, but I don't have a reference at hand.

[image: screenshot with deleted posts]

These are some of the deleted Q&A's with down votes:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/843390/user-without-a-name-was-logged-in
- https://serverfault.com/questions/782673/exchange-periodically-stops-delivering-emails/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/776435/is-it-possible-to-write-a-very-general-vhost-file-for-different-domains
- https://serverfault.com/questions/777642/build-php7-different-openssl-versions

Comment: Upvote for the 1st sentence. This _annoying thing_ lets me now look a bit stupid. I was convinced in the revision history the corrections for deleted questions are visible as I get revision deducted when a user is for example deleted. Now I understand it. It's pity even I cannot see the deleted questions. Especially with my own answers is it a kind of _wiki_ - for example: [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/777642/build-php7-different-openssl-versions). May be the SO developer can re-consider this.

Comment: @AlBundy  Just for my own curiosity, once the deleted posts are pointed out to you, can you follow the links and still see them, or are you blocked from **seeing** your own deleted posts too?

Comment: Yes, I can see all of your examples. Really, it's a pity I cannot access them. May be they are for the community worthless but they are documenting my issues and how I solved them.

Comment: I would edit to strike that 10K user can search deleted content from other users, but unsure of the etiquette :P It's a diamond avantage. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270554/10k-users-can-search-any-users-deleted-content I agree it worked in the past, but they fixed it as a bug (now it's blocked, unless diamond :), but at 10K you can list your own

Comment: @yagmoth555 Thanks for the info and updated accordingly, I have been a mod on ServerFault since 2015 and I'm not active enough on other sites to really be aware of what extra's come with high rep compared to what the diamond unlocks. (seeing versus searching for deleted posts is a subtle one)

Comment: @HBruijn: I've the same problem. I really wish for a `su` like tool where we could see the site as user X (just see, not post as of course).

Answer (score 5):

You have asked 12 questions, seven of which have been deleted automatically ([example](https://serverfault.com/questions/843390/user-without-a-name-was-logged-in)) or by yourself ([example](https://serverfault.com/questions/782673/exchange-periodically-stops-delivering-emails)).

This might be enough to trigger this warning.

Comment: And 7/12 probably exceeds a  threshold of  >50% resulting in the warning.